# Is there any solution for fetching metadata of Crossref using DOIs (Rest API calls)

Tags: python, python-requests

I am retrieving metadata of Crossref using crossref rest API

I have CSV file of DOIs from which I fetch DOI using python and make API call for each DOI to retrieve metadata from Crossref. I have to fetch metadata for many DOIs but after retrieving some metadata it gives connection error

```
import requests  

response = requests.get("https://api.crossref.org/v1/works/http://dx.doi.org/" + CitedDOI[X])
```

This is connection error

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.crossref.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1/works/http://dx.doi.org/10.1080/10426910802104344 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000019510E068D0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
import requests
import json

response = requests.get("https://api.crossref.org/works/YOUR_DOI")

print(response.json())
```

I also recommend looking at the [CrossRef API documentation](https://github.com/CrossRef/rest-api-doc). The rules change every now and then, but right now you can get faster speeds by

- Including your email address in a header
- Requesting multiple DOIs in a single call
- Multithreading requests (limited to 50 requests per-second at the time of writing)

Comment: Their documentation seems to have gaps. Currently trying to find out where I can request multiple DOIs. Their python wrapper can't do anything really and has not been improved since one year. I can do `/works/<doi>` but not `journals/<doi>` even though journals also have a doi. What a mess...

Comment: You can request multiple DOIs quite easily. Recommend no more than `batch_size=100` per API call. Batch size affects speed, so you might want to experiment. `dois_s = 'doi:' + ',doi:'.join(doi_batch)`, then optionally `dois_s = urllib.parse.quote(dois_s)`, then `url = r'https://api.crossref.org/works/?filter={}&rows={}'.format(dois_s, batch_size)`. Note that CrossRef are making major changes to their API, so the way to do things might change soon.

Comment: Thanks! So the filter is the krux. To me filter sounds like you are scrolling over the entire collection, filtering out certain records... Especially with the rows parameter which seems like in a scroll context. Maybe them making or planning changes is why I failed to extract this information from their documentations.

Comment: I don't know how it works, but I doubt that they could scan the whole db that fast. What I can say is that the more DOIs you request, the slower it goes. You can make 50 requests per second, but the speed is such that it's still quite limiting. If I try to do 50 requests of 100 DOIs in a second, it just cuts me off. So I recommend limiting to say 10 requests per second and 10 DOIs at a time. That seems optimal. You can use the `multiprocessing` Pool class. ex: https://github.com/sagepublishing/rejected_article_tracker_pkg/blob/main/rejected_article_tracker/src/ML/CrossRefUtils.py

Comment: yeah i am doing 16 individual request in parallel right now because I had not yet seen this way of requesting multiple dois. When I tried more it stopped responding. It is already limited to respond only once in ~0.37s apparently

Comment: There is also a complete snapshot of the dataset on academic torrents. You can download it with bittorrent and then mount it to a database of your choice (e.g. elasticsearch or MongoDB) https://academictorrents.com/details/0c6c3fbfdc13f0169b561d29354ea8b188eb9d63